# Как сделать чтобы не показывалась ссылка?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

При отправке сообщения высвечивается ссылка. Как сделать чтобы её не было? библиотека: discord.py[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так должно быть в вашей функции

```py
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="URL")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: а как туда текст добавить?

Comment: поменяйте первую строку на эту `embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description")`

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def tuk(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="По башке себе постучи!", color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J6IXRoE9wlY/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLBN_CvFIMpY6byQSSAQfZAesIYKZw&days_since_epoch=19035")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: вот результат:]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).